# Can you find an item from a list from the item's name in python?

Tags: python, string, list

So I was wondering if it was possible to find an item from a list by it's name. I am working on a very simple programming language, and with variables, there are two lists:

```
var_name = []
variable_data = []
```

And I have created an algorithm for assigning variables to these lists if you enter a command to assign a variable. Here is the code:

```
if 'var:> ' in user_input:
  varnames.append(user_input.replace('var:> ', "").split(', ', 1)[0])
  variable_data.append(re.sub(r'.*, ', "", user_input))
```

And if you're wondering, the code in my language for making a variable is:

```
var:> var_name, var_data
```

But, coding things like printing and inputs do not support variables because I need to create some sort of translator that can get an item from a list from a string input. For example, if there was a variable named x in my programming language, can you make some sort of translator that finds the x item in the list from a string named x?

For example:
If you wanted to print a variable, or:

```
print:var> x
```

Is there a form to create some sort of translator that translates that x and takes it to the "x" item in the variable name list?
Also, I was considering using a dictionary for this, so if its easier, you could make a method for that too.

Thanks.

Comment: `you could make a method for that too.` - Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 0):

Try using dictionary. Its a map that translates key to its value. **Key** must be immutable value like string, and **value** can be any python data-type. Dictionary suits perfectly for your application.

```
dict = {}
if 'var:> ' in user_input:
  key = user_input.replace('var:> ', "").split(', ', 1)[0]
  value = re.sub(r'.*, ', "", user_input)
  dict[key] = value
  # dict = {'var_name':'var_data'}
```

To get data for **x**. Use regex to get x from your input. Then get from dictionary

```
key = re.search(r'var>(?P<key>.*)', d).group('key').strip()
value = dict.get(key, "Variable not defined yet")
# gives value of x if exist, else return "Variable not defined yet"
```

Comment: Could you possibly explain this for me? I'm a beginner at python so I don't really get this stuff.

Comment: I've done nothing new. I just changed data type from list to dictionary. Rest of the code is same as yours. If you want to learn about dictionary, there are very good resources in the internet. [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm)